# Extend UserRoleStore in Asp.net Core Identity 2.1x

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-identity

I have an ASP.NET Core Identity 2.1x app that runs a multi-tenant, i.e. multi-portal environment.

I would like to extend the Identity role provider with some extension methods for `IUserRoleStore<TUser>.AddToRoleAsync` which takes an additional parameter (Portal/Tenant ID, in this case).

In this application, user accounts span across portals, but different users have different roles depending on the portal (i.e. tenant) in question.  I'm therefore looking to implement a sort of "role per tenant" functionality.

What would I need to do to extend the default `UserRoleStore` provider in this case?  I've already extended `UserManager<TUser>` with updated `AddToRoleAsync`, etc, methods, but those all rely on the `UserRoleStore` functionality that I can't figure out how to extend.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the [source](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/98a8d7a2be94f04f65e3463ab897fde58a62edb1/src/Identity/EntityFrameworkCore/src/UserStore.cs) it seems to be the case that `UserStore` inherits from `UserStoreBase` which implements `IUserRoleStore`. You can either create a class that inherits from `IUserRoleStore` and register it using DI. Or an other options will be inheriting from `UserStore`.